# importing data into r that can not be as numeric

Tags: r, import, read.csv

I use both read.csv and read.table for importing data as following, but it`s not as numeric.can you help me whats the problem?

```
x<-read.csv("D:\\r-files\\mydata1.csv",header=TRUE,dec = ".")
> is.numeric(x)
[1] FALSE
```

or

```
x<-read.csv("D:\\r-files\\mydata1.txt",header=TRUE,dec = ".")
> is.numeric(x)
[1] FALSE>
```

Comment: `x` is a dataframe and thus not numeric. I guess you are probably looking for `sapply(x, class)` instead.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I want to import my data as matrix, and I use (as.matrix(x)). There is an error that, the data is not numeric or vector.

Comment: Can you show what the top of the data or CSV look like? Can you run `sapply(x, class)` and see if it's one, some, or many columns giving you trouble?

Comment: thanks so much. the instruction was useful, and my problem was resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- read.csv(file="D:\\r-files\\mydata1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", dec = ".", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x <- as.matrix(x)
```

Hopefully this will solve your query.